# UISwipeGestureRecognizer not firing

Tags: objective-c, uiview, interface-builder, uigesturerecognizer, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have a UISwipeGestureRecognizer setup in IB linked to my view like so:

[image]

Extremely trivial, done it a million times. However this time it never fires >:|

Here is my method that *should* be called when a user swipes.

[image]

However this never gets called.

- No it's not accidentally added to a subview
- Yes the Pan gesture works perfectly.

I have another view setup almost exactly the same as this that works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add below `delegate` method in your `ViewController`

Returning `YES` is guaranteed to allow simultaneous recognition and returning `NO` is not guaranteed to prevent simultaneous recognition, as the other gesture's `delegate` may return `YES`

```
- (BOOL) gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
   return YES;
}
```

Comment: Had to wait for the 5min delay to go away :)

Comment: @Kamarshad: Thanks for solving a problem that took me 3 days to figure out :-)

Comment: Works like a charm, 10x :)